# Make setTimeout() work after closing and opening an application

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js, settimeout

So atm I'm working on a Discord.js bot and have a command to ban people. The issue is if I turn the bot off and on again all the setTimeouts reset. So say, if I were to ban someone for a week, turn the bot off  and on in between there, they will never automatically be unbanned.

```
setTimeout(function () {
                    memberTarget.roles.remove(bannedRole);
                }, ms(args[1]));
```

What other way could I use for it to remember to unban everyone after the bot has been turned on again?

Comment: Save the ban to persistant storage and set a new timer when when the bot starts again.

Comment: Short answer: You need to store data to database.

Comment: Or you can use https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-persist

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use database or data persist

Store bans data to database/data persist then set worker to check for unban (expiry).

> Database https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/nodejs/data-access-in-nodejs

> Data Persist https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-persist